# WalletConnect v2 not working with my wallet

Tags: uniswap, walletconnect, trustwallet

I can't get WalletConnect v2 to work at all with my wallet. I try using Uniswap to connect and scan the QR code with the Trust Wallet app. It thinks my ETH balance is 0 and spinners stuck on the token list. Same problem when trying on the phone itself.

I urgently need this sorted as v1 discontinues on 28th June (today) so I may lose access. Can someone help me fix this and get WalletConnect v2 working with my wallet?

Comment: So it seems iOS is the culprit. I have now installed Trust Wallet on my Android phone and it all now seems fine.

Comment: Please reach out to us via DM with your complaint and a short summary of your enquiry. if you’re still having issues with migrating
https://www.instagram.com/waletconnect/